# In the same way As / that

Tags: conjunctions

> 1. I treat Jhon in the same way as I do Jane.
> 2. I treat Jhon as I do Jane.
> 3. I treat Jhon like I do Jane.

I think these are all natural, but how about this?

> 4. I treat Jhon in the same way that I do Jane.

Is is right grammatically?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is grammatically correct, however it doesn't sound natural and I wouldn't expect a native English speaker to use it (although I suppose there might be some context in which it would be sensible).

Your third example,

> I treat Jhon like I do Jane.

although both grammatically correct and how a lot of native English speakers would word that concept, is something that would grate on the ears of quite a few people. It does sound somewhat *coarse*.

Comment: "I treat Jhon like I do Jane" is **not** correct. The _subordinating conjunction **as**_ is correct here: _I treat Jhon **as** I do Jane._ The usage might be fine in casual conversation, but it's just dumb to tell new learners that the _worst_ way to say something is grammatically correct.

Comment: Like, in an informal sense is not incorrect and if you read all of my answer, I do stress that it is not the preferred form.